# Where can I find my car seat instruction manual?

Tags: car-seat

The original manual was destroyed, and now I can't find it online.

The car seat is an Safety 1st Alpha Omega 65, Model # 22483C-AXN manufactured in 2011.

Safety 1st claims to have manuals online, but there is no list, only a search function, and no matter what I search it comes up no results.

Comment: http://safety1st.djgusa.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/InstructionSearchView?storeId=10154&catalogId=10051&langId=-1 is probably the right place to go - except it's down. I'd use the Contact Us link on http://djgusa.com/ .

Comment: Alternately, is [this](http://media.safety1st.com/~/media/safety1st/products/car-seats/infant-car-seats/us-alpha-omega-elite/manuals/usermanual_safety1st_alpha-omega-elite.ashx?vs=1&d=20140703T141739) correct?  I don't see exact model number, but it looks approximately right.

Comment: @joe That first link was correct and actually worked for me. The page I was trying (http://www.safety1st.ca/eng/Instructions) did not.  Thank you so much.  Make that an answer, and i'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saftey First has a search engine [here](http://safety1st.djgusa.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/InstructionSearchView?storeId=10154&catalogId=10051&langId=-1).

In general, one other option is to go to Amazon, where if you can find the exact same item, you may be able to get the manual from there.  In your case I didn't find it, however.

Answer (score 3):

I looked the model up and it said to contact them at this # and they will send you one in the mail. 1-800-544-1108

Answer (score 1):

Try this link: http://media.safety1st.com/~/media/safety1st/products/car-seats/infant-car-seats/us-alpha-elite-65/manuals/usermanual_safety1st_alpha-elite-65.ashx?vs=1&d=20140703T141738.  It's the manual for the model 65.